# Anyone have a working Apple 13" Trinitron display?

Tags: apple-macintosh

I'd like to add an image of the Trinitron's tungsten wire that was visible on the lower half of the Apple 13" display to [the Wikipedia article on the Trinitron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinitron).

If anyone has one of these monitors hooked up, can you take a photo of the entire screen with a white background (and thus no copyright issues) that shows it?

I'm not sure it will be visible in any photo that shows the whole screen, but I'd like to try.

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/ has an article on the Trinitron?